# Multiplying values in array by each other and checking the result against a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers

`const nums = [10, 7, 3, 47];`

I am looking to check if I multiply each number by itself will it match my result number. I have tried a long shot by doing the following

```
const x = nums[0] + nums[1]
const y = nums[0] + nums[2]
const z = nums[0] + nums[3]
const a = nums[1] + nums[2]
const b = nums[1] + nums[3]
const c = nums[2] + nums[3]
var k = 70

const ans = Math.imul(nums[0], nums[1])


console.log(ans)

function thisFunction(){
ans === k ? alert("Correct") : alert("not correct")
}
```

So my progress is , I can check if two values multiplied by each other is equal or not to my answer (k:70)

Tried using Math.imul (having searched) and that only multiplies two number? Would I be right to use .map in this case? Similar to

`const test = nums.map * nums.map`

any help is appreciated

Comment: where is `Math.imul` from?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/imul

Comment: Just in my searches I came across it, thought it might be the job.

Comment: I think simply `num[0] * num[1]` will do the trick. And what's the point of the other six variables with the sums?

Comment: I am trying to get the results of 10*7, 10*30, 10*47 etc. Rather than just the first two values in the array

Comment: use 2 forloops?

Comment: Right but your `x`, `y`, etc values are *sums*, not products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array.some` by passing it a function that checks if something is true for at least one item in the array. For this problem, there's 2 questions:

- An inner question of--if I have some other item in the array with value `v0` and index `i0`, is there any item in the array with value `v1` and index `i1` where `i0` and `i1` are different and the product of `v0` and `v1` equals the target? In javascript this function might look like this:

  ```
   // assume v0 and i0 are defined earlier
   (v1,i1) => i0 !== i1 && v0 * v1 === target
  ```

  So, to check it for any item in the array as `v1` and `i1`, we could use the `array.some` function like this:

  ```
   // assume v0 and i0 are defined earlier
   nums.some((v1,i1) => i0 !== i1 && v0 * v1 === target)
  ```
- An outer question of--is that inner question true for any item in the array with value `v0` and index `i0`? That function might look like this:

  ```
   (v0,i0) => nums.some((v1,i1) => i0 !== i1 && v0 * v1 === target)
  ```

  And so to check that for any item in the array as `v0` and `i0`, we could use the `array.some` function like this:

  ```
  nums.some((v0,i0) => 
      nums.some((v1,i1) => i0 !== i1 && v0 * v1 === target)
  );
  ```

So, to use nested `array.some` to check the product of differently-indexed values:

```js
const nums = [10, 7, 3, 47];
let target = 70;

let result = nums.some((v0,i0) =>
    nums.some((v1,i1) => i0 !== i1 && v0 * v1 === target)
);

console.log(result);
```

For a little more efficiency, use `array.slice` to only run the inner `some` on  whatever part of the array is after the index `i0`. This avoids having to check index equality and avoids multiplying pairs of items we've already tried in the opposite order.

```js
const nums = [10, 7, 3, 47];
let target = 70;

let result = nums.some((v0,i0) =>
    nums.slice(i0 + 1).some((v1) => v0 * v1 === target)
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What are the references to i0, v0?

Comment: @conye9980 I added an explanation to the top. I hope that helps clear things up

Comment: That's great mate, we'll explained, I'm going to have to take a good look at it to let it sink in

Comment: Just a follow up on this for clarification.
In the example: v0=10, i01=0(first position in the array)
In the nested array you are making sure i0 and i1 are not equal so as not to multiply the first array value by itself. So the nested array is saying the array positions are not the same and also checking if any values multiplied by another value is equal to the target number.
The .some method repeats this over the entire array then?

Comment: yep, you've got it. the outer `some` tests (up to) every item as `i0`/`v0` and the inner `some` tests (up to) every item as `i1`/`v1`. The inner `some` starts over every time the outer one tries a new item. And I say "(up to)" because as soon as `some` tries an item and the expression returns `true`, the `some` itself returns `true`. And it only returns false if it tried every item in the list and the expression was false every time.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a generator function which generates all pairs and check against the wanted product.

```js
function* getPairs(array, left) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (left !== undefined) yield [left, array[i]];
        else yield* getPairs(array.slice(i + 1), array[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

var nums = [10, 7, 3, 47],
    product = 70;

for (let [a, b] of getPairs(nums)) {
    if (product === a * b) {
        console.log(a, b);
        break;
    }
}
```

A solution without a generator function, but with two nested loops where the first runs for each index but the last and the second from the other index plus one to the end.

The loops takes all possible pairs of the array.

```js
var nums = [10, 7, 3, 47],
    product = 70,
    i, j;

for (i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {       // because last element goes into other loop
    for (j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        if (product === nums[i] * nums[j]) {
            console.log(nums[i], nums[j]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with generator functions, so will leave this for anyone else who is looking.
https://codeburst.io/understanding-generators-in-es6-javascript-with-examples-6728834016d5